# Как создать шаблон класса и потом создать и вызвать функцию типа данного класса?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Добрый день! Имеется код:

```
class Newclass
{
 int x;
 int y;
 type z;
}

Newclass Newfunction(parametrtype1);
Newclass Newfunction2(parametrtype1);

Newclass Newfunction (parametrtype1 parametrname)
{
 //тело функции
}
Newclass Newfunction2 (parametrtype1 parametrname)
{
 //тело функции
}

int main()
{
parametrtype1 variable;
 //вызов функции
Newfunction(variable);
Newfunction2(variable);
}
```

Дело в том, что по задумке член класса Newclass z - должен получить различные типы данных, в зависимости от того, что возвращает функция. Это можно реализовать с помощью шаблонов, но в данный момент я не могу разобраться, как это реализовать. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вот:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Newclass {
public:
  int x;
  int y;
  T z;

  Newclass(T z): z(z) {}
  void Newfunction2(T value) {
    std::cout << this->z << " " << value << std::endl;
  }
};


int return_variable(){
  std::cout << "return int(1)" << std::endl;
  return 1;
}


int main() {
  auto value = return_variable();
  Newclass<decltype(value)> c(value);
  c.Newfunction2(1);
}
```

Это есть в документации языка.